# Show/hide preview of Raspivid on runtime

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, raspivid

Is there any possibility to hide/show preview of video on runtime?
I know there is only signal event handler to pause recording but I don't see possibility to control behaviour of Raspivid via DBus or other way.
There is also no chance to run two separate instances of Raspivid.
I could start one Raspivid to record to file and second one only to preview purpose if needed but there is no possibility to start two Raspivid apps.
I consider using omxplayer but omxplayer starts very slowly and I would prefer to ommit this solution because of other apps running on board (I mean this approach: https://wiki.marcluerssen.de/index.php?title=Raspberry_Pi/Camera_streaming )